# PUT method does'nt work in AngularJs

Tags: html, angularjs, spring

Im stuck because I have to create an Update method for my work but with AngularJs the form is not taking the ng-model information. I don't know why. because 2 hours before I managed to do it easily with a simple POST method.

Here is the code in my controller:

```
$scope.UpdateData = function (petId) {      
    $http({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: baseApiUrl + '/pets/' + petId,
        data: {
            id: petId,
            name: $scope.updateName,
            age: $scope.updateAge,
            owner: $scope.updateOwner,
        }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
};
```

And this is my view:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr class="text-center pointer back-grey">
      <th class="text-red">
        Nom
      </th>
      <th class="text-red">
        Age
      </th>
      <th class="text-red">
        Propriétaire
      </th>
      <th class="text-red">
        Action
      </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="pet in pets">
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="{{ pet.name }}" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="updateName" required></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="{{ pet.age }}" name="age" class="form-control" ng-model="updateAge" required></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="{{ pet.owner }}" name="owner" class="form-control" ng-model="updateOwner" required></td>
        <td><input id="update" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger disabled" ng-click="UpdateData(pet.id)" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I change the values of my form, and press the button I have this :

```
Object {data: "1", status: 200, config: Object, headers: function}
```

The id is the to petId as I asked, but the name doesn't change. And when I change $scope.updateName by a string like "hello" this is working...

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same variable for all objects 'pet'. So, if you have two pets there will be two inputs for the same variable 'updateName', this could lead to undefined behaviour. 
I suggest you to do something like this:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="pet in pets track by $index">
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="{{ pet.name }}" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="updateName[$index]" required></td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="{{ pet.age }}" name="age" class="form-control" ng-model="updateAge[$index]" required></td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="{{ pet.owner }}" name="owner" class="form-control" ng-model="updateOwner[$index]" required></td>
    <td><input id="update" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger disabled" ng-click="UpdateData($index)" /></td>
</tr>


$scope.UpdateData = function (idx) {      
    $http({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: baseApiUrl + '/pets/' + petId,
        data: {
            id: $scope.pets[idx],
            name: $scope.updateName[idx],
            age: $scope.updateAge[idx],
            owner: $scope.updateOwner[idx],
        }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
};
```

Comment: I did what you suggested but I still have this error when I try to write something inside the fields : TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined.

Comment: it seems like you doesn't have initiliaze the arrays. You have to do this on the scope initilization: **$scope.updateAge = [];** And so for all arrays;